# In native mail app desktop and mobile images loading issue

Tags: html, css

Hope you are all having a great day!!

Need one help. I am working on a mail template. During testing it on mobile I found out that for native mail apps for android and ios the template is having images for the desktop and mobile.

I have tested separately for yahoo and gmail app on mobile ,there it is working properly. It is only rendering mobile image for yahoo and gmail.

I have tested following scenarios:

Sucessful Testing 
1. Tested on internet explorere for yahoo and gmail 
2. Tested on chrome for yahoo and gmail 
3. Tested on android for yahoo and gmail app

Failed Testing 1. Andriod Native Mail app(showing both desktop and mobile images) 
2. IOs Native Mail app(showing both desktop and mobile images)

Please any one can help me with this issue?

Comment: Please review the guidelines for posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make sure you post code so we can help you.